# create rotated pdf-file without rotation meta-data

Tags: java, pdfbox

I got a little java project working with PDFBox 2.0.6 . In this project you can upload a .pdf-file and then add markers in form of font-awesome icons, horizontal lines, or rectangles to it by just giving a x and y coordinate and the width (line) or width and height (rectangle). You can also add text which is placed in relative position to the marker or inside the box, with neat little spacing alogrithm. You can see your progress in a preview next to it.
Everything works fine until someone uploaded a pdf-document which was rotated by in this case 270 degree. The original document was in portrait orientation, but someone scanned it in landscape orientation and the just rotated the pdf by 270 degree. My preview will now show the document in its rotated form (portrait) and if you add a line under the documents headline it all looks fine. When I now try to create pdf with this line, it adds the line to the pdPage, but because of its rotation, its coordinates are off and the line will appear in a different corner.
**Now to my question:**
Before I change all my code, minding the rotation of the document (which is like 4 times the code and I have to think of it everytime I add a new feature) is there any way to create a new (temporary) file which is in portrait orientation but has a 0 degree rotation in its metadata, so that I can than add my markers to this document instead?
Thank you in advance! :3

Comment: In short: No. In detail: Well, you can but it's a hell of a lot of work; it requires adding the page rotation to the page content, changing the page boxes, changing the positions and dimensions of annotations, adding the rotation to annotation appearances, changing of coordinates in some annotation meta data, changing coordinates and dimensions in layout tags, and probably even more. For the simple scan you mentioned it would be feasible (most likely it has no annotations or layout tags) but not in general.

Comment: What you can do, though, is to start your additions to the page content stream with a transformation that consequentially is applied to all your additions and rotates the coordinate system according to the page rotation. As we don't see your pivotal code, though, it is difficult to add that transformation to it.

Comment: The transformation of the annotations via code, or the code especially in that matter, wasn't part of my question, that I know how to do but it's just a lot of work, which as the lazy programmer as we all are, I'd like to avoid if there's an easier way to do it ;)

Comment: *"it's just a lot of work"* - not really... ;)